# Is it possible to make a Template Literal that does not accept certain substring Template Literal?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have types like this

```js
type PhotosTemplate = `user/${string}/photos/${string}`
type ScreenshotsTemplate = `${PhotosTemplate}/screenshots/${string}`
```

This is very useful to me, because it makes the code below invalid:

```js
const alicePhoto1: PhotosTemplate = `user/alice/photos/photo1.png`
const aliceScreenshot1: ScreenshotsTemplate = alicePhoto1
// Type '`user/${string}/photos/${string}`' is not assignable to type '`user/${string}/photos/${string}/screenshots/${string}`'.(2322)
```

But it causes annoyance because the code below is perfectly and rightfully valid:

```js
const bobScreenshot1 = `user/bob/photos/screenshots/screenshot1.png`
const bobPhoto1: PhotosTemplate = bobScreenshot1
```

It is possible to make two Template Literal types to exclude each other? Like a "PhotosTemplate & not ScreenshotsTemplate" type?

Comment: No, you need a function for that. Or you could use `satisfies` but that's redundant.

Comment: I already have a function doing that, but doing it at compile time would improve developer experience at my team.

Comment: No no, a function with a *compile time check*: https://tsplay.dev/mb3roW